# Three Button RelativeLayout with View Dividers

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-view, android-button

I'm trying to create a better looking button bar for my app to match the theme.
So far, I'm using the following code:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/footer"
    style="@android:style/ButtonBar"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Formula"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Formula" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Solve"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Solve" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Clear"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Clear" />
</LinearLayout>
```

And it gives me a result like this:
[image]

I'm also working on some code to replace that bar with a better looking one. It is as follows:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" >

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dip"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="4dip"
        android:background="@drawable/black_white_gradient" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/ViewOne"
        android:layout_width="1dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dip"
        android:background="@drawable/black_white_gradient" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/ButtonOne"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/ViewOne"
        android:background="@color/button_blue_background"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:text="Cancel"
        android:textColor="@color/button_dark_text" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/ButtonTwo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/ViewOne"
        android:background="@color/button_blue_background"
        android:text="OK"
        android:textColor="@color/button_dark_text" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Which results in:
[image]

So my issue is that I'm unable to get three buttons on the new black bar. I've tried adding more views and buttons with the android:layout_toRightOf attributes but it still won't work.
Are there any ideas on what I could possibly do to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to add Views to the layour just to show your gradients.

I suggest you to use your *LinearLayout* with those three buttons and set a *layer-list* xml as the background of the layout itself.

1. Create the layer-list xml file, eg, **layerlist.xml** with your gradients:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
      <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/gradient1"
        android:id="@+id/grad1"
      />

      <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/gradient2"
        android:id="@+id/grad2"
      />
   </layer-list>
   ```

   If you have just one gradient then you don't need a layer-list xml file. Set it directly as background of the *LinearLayout*.
2. As I said before, set the **layerlist.xml** (or your single gradient xml file) as background of the layout:

   ```
   <LinearLayout
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:id="@+id/footer"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:gravity="bottom"
     android:orientation="horizontal"
     android:background="@drawable/layerlist" >

       <Button
         android:id="@+id/Formula"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_weight="1"
         android:text="Formula" />

      <Button
         android:id="@+id/Solve"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_weight="1"
         android:text="Solve" />

      <Button
         android:id="@+id/Clear"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_weight="1"
         android:text="Clear" />
   </LinearLayout>
   ```

Let me know if it works!

**EDIT:**

As far as I know, you can define a proper height to the gradient. Add `android:top="3dp"` to the desired **item** of your *layerlist.xml* file. That means your gradient will have height of 3dp starting from the top.
Or, if you are using a single gradient file you can define the grandient's height adding to your shape:

```
<size
      android:height="3dp" />
```

Comment: I like your solution but it didn't really work.
Here's what happened: http://i49.tinypic.com/2ezpvlj.png
Since my buttons are transparent until clicked and the gradient looks rather weird.

Comment: The ideia is to make the gradient that horizontal line above the buttons, right? The gradient is assuming all the LinearLayout height but you can define the proper height of the gradient, it seems like, 2 or 3dp.

Comment: I've edited my answer, check it out, please. I think it might help you.

Comment: Okay, I tried it and it looks better but it's still missing the vertical dividers which is what I am having issues with the most.

Also, I tried making the button background from transparent to black by default to see if that would work and it did. However, my app's activity background is a gradient (light gray to black) so it didn't really match like I thought.

Comment: You can do the same thing with shapes. The only thing you have to do is create another gradient file for your buttons but with a vertical line instead of and set it as background too.

Comment: I don't know how to do that.
But either way, I just realized my text wouldn't be visible if I kept it how I wanted. Everything seems to be perfect by following your code and modified my buttons' backgrounds to be black.

Thank you!
http://i50.tinypic.com/9j17r7.png

Comment: Okay. I'm glad to help. Accept my answer if you think it really helped you, please.

Answer (score 0):

For the "three buttons" case, you can set the LinearLayour attribute `android:weightSum="3"` That should give you three buttons of equal size.

Comment: Tried it but eclipse gave me this: error: No resource identifier found for the attribute 'layout_weightsum' in package 'android'

Comment: I changed it. Sorry about that.

Comment: It's still giving me a similar error. 
I think it's because RelativeLayout does not support weightsums like LinearLayout.

Comment: No, RelativeLayout doesn't support it. I thought you were still using the LinearLayout. Sorry about that.